Imageview does not keep the selected image after changing activity
I have a MainActivity and a EditActivity, Main shows default info, then it can be changed on EditActivity which sends new info to MainActivity. Edit has a ImageView "@+id/edit_profile_picture", and a button "@+id/changephotobutton" to change the image with ACTION_GET_CONTENT, passing uri from EditActivity to MainActivity works and image is correctly setted on @+id/main_profile_picture, but when I get again into the EditActivity the @+id/edit_profile_picture is emptyl. If I save changes using action_save the picture I set before stills in MainActivity.
I just want to keep the photo in both imageviews until I change it, and I wanna know how to set a default drawable ("@drawable/img_avatar")
when app is open (because its blank when app is open) and when picture is removed (i have an "@+id/deletephotobutton" but I haven't configure it yet).
MainActivity:
package com.example.perfil

import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate
import com.example.perfil.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    public var UbicationButtomTest: Int = 0
    private var lat: Double = 0.0`your text`
    private var lon: Double = 0.0
    private lateinit var receiveimage: ImageView
    private var uriString: String? = null
    private var uri: Uri? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        updateUI()

            binding.profileMostrar.setOnClickListener {
                if (UbicationButtomTest==0) {
                    binding.profileMostrar.text = "Lat: $lat, Lon: $lon"
                    UbicationButtomTest=1
                }
                else if (UbicationButtomTest==1) {
                    binding.profileMostrar.text = "Mostrar mapa"
                    UbicationButtomTest=0
                }
            }

        receiveimage = findViewById(R.id.main_profile_picture)
    }

    private fun updateUI(
        name: String = "Asking to Stack Overflow",
        correo: String = "stack@overflow.com",
        web: String = "https://stackoverflow.com",
        phone: String = "+01 2345678910")

    {
        binding.profileTvNombre.text = name
        binding.profileTvCorreo.text = correo
        binding.profileTvWeb.text = web
        binding.profileTvPhone.text = phone

    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }



    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (item.itemId == R.id.action_edit) {
            val intent = Intent(this, EditActivity::class.java)
            val uriString = uri.toString()
            intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.img_to_editactivity), uriString)
            intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.k_name), binding.profileTvNombre.text.toString().trim())
            intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.k_email), binding.profileTvCorreo.text.toString().trim())
            intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.k_web), binding.profileTvWeb.text.toString().trim())
            intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.k_phone), binding.profileTvPhone.text.toString().trim())
            intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.k_lat), lat.toString())
            intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.k_lon), lon.toString())

            //startActivity(Intent) <-Solo lanza una vista
            //startActivity(intent) //<- Lanza y espera una respuesta
            editResult.launch(intent)
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    private val editResult =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
            if (it.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                val name = it.data?.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.k_name))
                val correo = it.data?.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.k_email))
                val web = it.data?.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.k_web))
                val phone = it.data?.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.k_phone))
                lat = it.data?.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.k_lat))?.toDouble() ?: 0.0
                lon = it.data?.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.k_lon))?.toDouble() ?: 0.0
                uriString = it.data?.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.img_to_mainactivity)) // Get the Uri string
                if (uriString != null) {
                    val uri = Uri.parse(uriString)  // Recreate the Uri
                    receiveimage.setImageURI(uri)
                    uriString = uri.toString()
                }
                updateUI(name!!, correo!!, web!!, phone!!)
            }
        }
}

EditActivity:
package com.example.perfil

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Patterns
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.perfil.databinding.ActivityEditBinding


class EditActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityEditBinding
    lateinit var changephotobutton: Button
    lateinit var deletephotobutton: Button
    lateinit var Imageviewineditactivity: ImageView
    private var uri: Uri? = null
    private var uriString: String? = null
    private var restoreUri: Uri? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityEditBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.etnombre.setText(intent.extras?.getString(getString(R.string.k_name)))
        binding.etcorreo.setText(intent.extras?.getString(getString(R.string.k_email)))
        binding.etsitioweb.setText(intent.extras?.getString(getString(R.string.k_web)))
        binding.etphone.setText(intent.extras?.getString(getString(R.string.k_phone)))
        binding.etlat.setText(intent.extras?.getString(getString(R.string.k_lat)).toString())
        binding.etlon.setText(intent.extras?.getString(getString(R.string.k_lon)).toString())

        changephotobutton = findViewById(R.id.changephotobutton)
        deletephotobutton = findViewById(R.id.deletephotobutton)
        Imageviewineditactivity = findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_picture)

        changephotobutton.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).apply {
                type = "image/*"
            }
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
        }

        // Recuperar estado si existe
        var uri = savedInstanceState?.getParcelable<Uri>("restoreUri")
        uri?.let {
            Imageviewineditactivity.setImageURI(it)
        }



        /*
        uriString = intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.img_to_editactivity))
        if (uriString != null) {
            uri = Uri.parse(uriString)
            Imageviewineditactivity.setImageURI(uri)
        }

         */
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == 1 && data != null) {
            uri = data.data // Assuming you have a 'uri' property declared
            Imageviewineditactivity.setImageURI(uri)
            }
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        // Guardar estado
        outState.run {
            putParcelable("restoreUri", uri)
        }
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        // Recuperar estado
        uri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable<Uri>("restoreUri")
        Imageviewineditactivity.setImageURI(uri)
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_edit,menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }





    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (item.itemId == R.id.action_save) {
            /*if (DataValidation()==true) {
                sendData()
            }*/
            sendData()
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }



    fun sendData() {
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.img_to_mainactivity), uri?.toString())
        intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.k_name), binding.etnombre.text.toString())
        intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.k_email), binding.etcorreo.text.toString())
        intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.k_web), binding.etsitioweb.text.toString())
        intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.k_phone), binding.etphone.text.toString())
        intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.k_lat), binding.etlat.text.toString())
        intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.k_lon), binding.etlon.text.toString())
        setResult(RESULT_OK,intent)
        finish()
    }

    private fun DataValidation(): Boolean{
        var ValidationBooleanStatus = true
    //..........
    }

}

activity_main.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/common_padding"
        >

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/radio_size_img"
            app:cardElevation="@dimen/card_elevation"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/common_padding"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main_profile_picture"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_image"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/size_image"
                tools:src="@drawable/img_avatar"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                />
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_nombre"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_margin"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_tv_nombre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_md"
            tools:text="Nombre"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_correo"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_margin"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_tv_correo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_md"
            tools:text="correo@mail.com"
            android:autoLink="email"
            android:textColorLink="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="italic|bold"
            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_sitio_web"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_margin"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_tv_web"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_md"
            tools:text="www.sitioweb.org"
            android:textColorLink="#00796B"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:textStyle="italic|bold"
            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_phone"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_margin"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_tv_phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_md"
            tools:text="+52 22 90 90 90 90"
            android:autoLink="phone"
            android:textColorLink="#009688"
            android:textStyle="italic|bold"
            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_location"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_margin"
            />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_mostrar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_show_location"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_margin"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_md"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/icon_map"
            />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/profileLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_habilitar_ubicacion"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_margin"
            android:textColor="#807575"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_md"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon_settings"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

activity_edit.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".EditActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/common_padding"
        >
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/size_image"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/size_image">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/image_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/edit_profile_picture"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    tools:src="@drawable/img_avatar" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/changephotobutton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                    android:text="Cambiar foto" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/deletephotobutton"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                    android:text="X" />

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/box_nombre"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/common_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_padding"
            android:hint="@string/text_nombre"
            >
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/etnombre"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/box_correo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/common_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_padding"
            android:hint="@string/text_correo"
            >
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/etcorreo"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/box_web"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/common_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_padding"
            android:hint="@string/text_sitio_web"
            >
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/etsitioweb"
                android:inputType="textWebEditText"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/box_contacto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/common_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_padding"
            android:hint="@string/text_phone"
            >
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/etphone"
                android:inputType="phone"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_padding"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/common_padding"
            >
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/box_lat"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:hint="@string/txt_lat"
                >
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/etlat"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/min_margin"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
                    />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/box_lon"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:hint="@string/txt_lon"
                >
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/etlon"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
                    />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

strings.xml:
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Perfil</string>
    <string name="text_nombre">Nombre</string>
    <string name="text_correo">Correo</string>
    <string name="text_sitio_web">Sitio Web</string>
    <string name="text_phone">Contacto</string>
    <string name="text_location">Ubicación</string>
    <string name="text_show_location">Mostrar mapa</string>
    <string name="text_habilitar_ubicacion">Habilitar ubicación</string>
    <string name="mm_modificar_info">Modificar Info.</string>
    <string name="txt_lat">Latitud</string>
    <string name="txt_lon">Longitud</string>
    <string name="k_name">k_name</string>
    <string name="k_email">k_email</string>
    <string name="k_web">k_web</string>
    <string name="k_phone">k_phone</string>
    <string name="k_lat">k_lat</string>
    <string name="k_lon">k_lon</string>
    <string name="img_to_editactivity">img_to_editActivity</string>
    <string name="img_to_mainactivity">img_to_mainActivity</string>
</resources>


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
